# How to implement a multiple prediction custom loss function in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, image-classification

I am trying to implement a Custom Loss function that uses multiple predictions/forward propagations of images for an image classification model.

The general concept of this loss function is to evaluate the model's consistency with non-augmented and augmented images. That is to say, the model is given 2 images; the original image and its augmented counterpart. Then, both images are forward propagated through the model. The more different the two outputs are from each other, the higher the loss.

What this meant is a fairly low-level change, and the most apparent way of solving this, to me, was model subclassing. I created a subclass of the keras.Model class and changed the train_step() method to include a small algorithm for locating the respective augmented counterpart of each original image (not relevant to the issue at all), and more significantly, a line that gave a prediction on the augmented counterpart:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
        y_aug = self(self.augmented_data[aug_index:aug_index+self.batch_size], training=True)
        
        loss = self.comparative_loss(y, y_pred, y_aug)
```

The whole `self.augmented_data[aug_index:aug_index+self.batch_size]` isn't relevant at all, it can be thought of just as the augmented data input. The intent was for the method "comparative_loss" to take the two predictions and then perform the aforementioned loss calculations on it.

The issue came when I tried to compile the model; there was a required loss parameter, but it refused to accept my custom loss method as it required 3 parameters. I couldn't go with the standard fix of putting the functions into a structure like this:

```
def new_loss(extra_parameter):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
         return loss_value
    return loss
```

since my "extra_parameter" was not just a standard output of the model; it was a completely separate forward propagation on it, that relied on my custom train_step() method.

TL;DR:

What I'm most confused about is, why does tf.compile() even require a loss function, if my "train_step" method doesn't use it? The train_step method in my custom subclass has the loss built-in, so **is there a way to override the .compile()'s loss parameter** and have it work without me having to give it a method? If not, what other solutions are there?

The full code is below, though I sincerely apologize to anyone that reads it, as it's not quite finished:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Feb 18 11:37:08 2022

Custom Loss Function 

Description:

For each element of y_true, compare the y_predict of
the original image and the complemented one, then return
a loss accordingly using the Euclidian distance 
between the predictions for the original images and the complements.

y_predict are labels for the images, these labels can 
come in any form: CIFAR labels, species labels, or labels of which
individual a given image is. 

y_predict will be in the shape (batch_size, number_of_classes), using the 

@author: hudso
"""
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten, BatchNormalization
import ssl
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

class CustomModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, classes):
        super().__init__() #call parent constructor
        self.conv_1 = Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same')
        self.batch_1 = BatchNormalization()
        self.conv_2 = Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same')
        self.batch_2 = BatchNormalization()
        self.pool_1 = MaxPooling2D((2,2))
        self.conv_3 = Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same')
        self.batch_3 = BatchNormalization()
        self.conv_4 = Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same')
        
        self.batch_4 = BatchNormalization()
        self.pool_2 = MaxPooling2D((2,2))
        self.conv_5 = Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same')
        self.batch_5 = BatchNormalization()
        self.conv_6 = Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same')
        
        self.batch_6 = BatchNormalization()
        self.flatten = Flatten()
        self.layer_1 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)
        self.layer_2 = Dense(256,activation='relu')
        self.dropout = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)
        self.outputs = Dense(classes, activation='softmax') #no. of classes
        
        self.classes = classes #Initializes the number of classes variable
    
    #essentially the Functional API forward-pass call-structure shenanigans
    #called each forward propagation (calculating loss, training, etc.)
    def call(self, inputs):
        #print("INPUTS: " + str(inputs))
        x = self.conv_1(inputs)
        x = self.batch_1(x)
        x = self.conv_2(x)
        x = self.batch_2(x)
        x = self.pool_1(x)
        x = self.conv_3(x)
        x = self.batch_3(x)
        x = self.conv_4(x)
        
        x = self.batch_4(x)
        x = self.pool_2(x)
        x = self.conv_5(x)
        x = self.batch_5(x)
        x = self.conv_6(x)
        
        x = self.batch_6(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.layer_1(x)
        x = self.layer_2(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.outputs(x)
        
        return x #returns the constructed model
    
    #Imports necessary data (It's hard to gain access of the values handed to .fit())
    def data_import(self, augmented_data, x_all, batch_size):
        self.augmented_data = augmented_data
        self.x_all = np.asarray(x_all, dtype=np.float32)
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        
    #Very useful advice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65889381/going-from-a-tensorarray-to-a-tensor
    def comparative_loss(self, y_true, y_pred, y_aug):
        output_loss = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=self.classes)
        batch_loss = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=self.batch_size)
        for n in range(self.batch_size):
            for i in range(self.classes):
                output_loss = output_loss.write(i, tf.square(tf.abs(tf.subtract(y_pred[n][i], y_aug[n][i])))) #finds Euclidean Distance for each prediction, then averages the loss across all iterations in the batch
            indexes = tf.keras.backend.arange(0, self.classes, step=1, dtype='int32')
            output_loss_tensor = output_loss.gather(indexes)
            batch_loss = batch_loss.write(n, tf.math.reduce_sum(output_loss_tensor))
        indexes = tf.keras.backend.arange(0, self.batch_size, step=1, dtype='int32')
        batch_loss_tensor = batch_loss.gather(indexes)
        total_loss = tf.math.reduce_sum(batch_loss_tensor)
        total_loss = tf.math.divide(total_loss, self.batch_size)
        print("TOTAL LOSS: " + str(total_loss))
        
        return total_loss
        
    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = data #Current batch
        
        #Finds the range of indexes for the complements of the current batch of images
        #A lower level implementation could make this significantly more efficient by avoiding searching each time
        aug_index = 0
        x_arr = x.numpy() #Turns the input data iterable Tensor into a numpy array, Eager Execution must be enabled for this to work
        for i in range(np.size(self.x_all, axis = 0)):
            difference = cv.subtract(self.x_all[i], x_arr[0])
            if np.count_nonzero(difference) == 0: #In the .fit() line for this CustomModel, shuffle = False for this to work
                aug_index = i #Lower bound of the batch of images
                found = True
        if found == False:
            print("Yikes mate the x_arr wasn't found in x_all... probably a rounding error")
        print("\nCurrent Index: " + str(aug_index))
        
        #Forward pass/predictions + loss calculation
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)
            y_aug = self(self.augmented_data[aug_index:aug_index+self.batch_size], training=True)
            
            loss = self.comparative_loss(y, y_pred, y_aug) #Computes the actual loss value
        
        #I didn't touch any of this code
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
   
#Essentially emulates the environment that the model would normally be running in
#E.g. Creates the dataset, does Image Augmentation, etc.
#In the actual implementation, only the "CustomModel" class will be used, this is purely for testing purposes
class shrek_is_love: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.complements = []
        self.create_dataset()
    
    #automatically runs
    def create_dataset(self):
        ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
        (images, labels), (_, _) = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data() #only uses the training sets and then splits it again later since that'll be what we'll be dealing with in the happywhale dataset anyways
        self.labels = labels
        self.images = images
        self.data_aug()
        
    #NOT MY CODE this is liam's image data generator (thx liam ur cool)
    #automatically runs
    def data_aug(self): 
        imageGen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=.3, height_shift_range=.3, horizontal_flip=True, zoom_range=.3)
        imagees = np.zeros(shape=(1, 32, 32, 3))
        for l in range(np.size(self.images, 0)): 
            # adjust the tuple inside of cv.resize to adjust resolution
            temp = cv.resize(self.images[l], (32, 32))
            imagees[0] = (cv.cvtColor(temp, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        
            it = imageGen.flow(imagees)
            im = it.next()
            im = im[0].astype('float32')
        
            im = im / 255.0
            self.complements.append(im)
        self.complements = np.asarray(self.complements, dtype=np.float)
        self.images = self.images.astype(np.float)
        self.images = self.images / 255.0
        self.preprocessor()
        
    def preprocessor(self):
        from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
        onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
        self.labels = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(np.reshape(self.labels, (-1, 1)))
        
        from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
        shared_seed = 5 #the indexes of complements_train and image_train have to line up, so that labels_train can apply to both
        self.complements_train, self.complements_test = train_test_split(self.complements, test_size=0.25, random_state=shared_seed)
        self.images_train, self.images_test, self.labels_train, self.labels_test = train_test_split(self.images, self.labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=shared_seed)
        
#The following code will be all that is necessary to run the CustomModel classs
batch_size = 32
shrek_is_life = shrek_is_love()
model = CustomModel(10) #10 classes
model.data_import(shrek_is_life.complements_train, shrek_is_life.images_train, batch_size) #the model will not be training on aug_data, essentially turning it into a secondary test set
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=None, metrics=['accuracy'], run_eagerly=True) #loss=None brings up an error, but I have no idea what else to put in there
model.fit(x = shrek_is_life.images_train, y = shrek_is_life.labels_train, shuffle = False, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = 1)
```

EDIT:
Running it without a .compile line yields this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\Downloads\untitled0.py", line 191, in <module>
    model.fit(x = shrek_is_life.images_train, y = shrek_is_life.labels_train, shuffle = False, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = 1)

  File "C:\Users\hudso\anaconda3\envs\mlTens\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1150, in fit
    x, y, sample_weights = self._standardize_user_data(

  File "C:\Users\hudso\anaconda3\envs\mlTens\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 508, in _standardize_user_data
    raise RuntimeError('You must compile a model before '

RuntimeError: You must compile a model before training/testing. Use `model.compile(optimizer, loss)`.
```

Running .compile without the loss argument or with loss=None yields:

```
  File "C:\Users\hudso\anaconda3\envs\mlTens\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 706, in _prepare_total_loss
    raise ValueError('The model cannot be compiled '

ValueError: The model cannot be compiled because it has no loss to optimize.
```

Comment: You do not have to compile your model at all when using a custom training step.

Comment: And even if you do compile (e.g. with an optimizer and metrics), the `loss` argument is _not_ obligatory. If you get an error please, add the actual error & traceback to the question...

Comment: Thanks, though it still gave an error (see the post for the aforementioned errors)